# Does Console.Read block in a windows application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am constantly switching to console mode from windows application mode when debugging. If my application is in Windows mode, will Console.Read and Console.ReadLine wait for user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Windows Application, `Console.Read` will always return -1, `Console.ReadLine` will return `null`, `ReadToEnd` will return `string.Empty`, and `Peek` will return `-1`;

This is because the `Console` class will automatically install a custom `StreamReader` to `Console.In` so these calls avoid being problematic.

Answer (score 1):

No, they will not. They will act as if they didn't exist. One thing to note, though, is that *ReadKey* will throw an exception rather than ignore it like the other two. If you need to check whether you are in a console or not see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957440).

Comment: what is going on here?  You asked a question and answered it yourself - in under 60 seconds?

Comment: There is a checkbox in the question form. I thought this might be really useful so I posted it.