# How to detect internally whether the application is in console or windows mode in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Is there a way to check whether a program is in console or windows mode from within the application itself? I know that Read and ReadLine can somehow detect this, but how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to check to see if `Console.In == StreamReader.Null;`

If this is true, there is no console attached.  For example, the following works properly for this:

```
public static bool IsConsoleApplication
{
    get { return Console.In != StreamReader.Null; }
}
```

Comment: @ArlenBeiler You mean as a property?  Can you show the code you want, usage wise?  I can show you how to make it work then...

Comment: Yeah, is there any particular reason to use a method?

Comment: @ArlenBeiler Not really - made it a property for you.  I was more just showing you the actual code as an example ;)

Comment: @ArlenBeiler I always use methods if there is "computation" involved - and often if the types being checked are external.  It just suggests that there's "something happening" inside of the method.  In this case, a property is perfectly appropriate, since a single comparison check like this is effectively free.  I think I gravitated towards a method since I was checking properties in two other, completely unrelated classes - but a property here is fine, too